# Keep form and controls proportion deployng a c# application for any screen size

Tags: c#, winforms, screen, screen-resolution

I know this is an "already heard" problem: I have searched a lot but I did not find anything that cleared my mind.

I am developing a c# application with a GUI containing some controls like buttons (made with images) and text.

I developed it setting the main form size to 800x600 but now I need the application to work also on a 1920x1080 screen.

Two problems:

1. If I position a button near the top-right corner of the main form and set `AnchorStyles` to Top-Right, when I switch to the big screen, the button is (in proportion) much more close to top-left corner than in the little screen (because the anchor keeps the distance from the border). Is there a way to set a proportional distance from the border?
2. How can I scale the dimensions of the controls proportionally to the screen size? Shall I use `AutoScaleMode` like suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx)?

Comment: A screenshot of form should have helped!

Comment: Use of Panel control will be helpful.

Comment: I know this might not be within the realm of possibilities (due to company constraints, for example) so I'm not putting this as an answer, but you should consider using WPF instead of WinForms. WPF has better ways to attain resolution-independence because it uses SVG and not BitMap as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add a capability to a form at design time - the ToolTip control does it, that makes properties available to every control on a form.  These are called 
"Extender Providers"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171836 
You would want to look at the controls, and cache their sizes and fonts at design time, and the size of the form.
The provider would hang off the form.SizeChanged event at run time.  When the size changes, you use the new and original (design time) sizes of the form to calculate and X and Y ratio.  You then go through each control and use it's design time size and the ratios to determine its new size and font size.  This can get flaky if you allow the user to select sizes that are not the same aspect ratio as your original.
Anyway, that is how it was done in Delphi, and everyone knows if you can do it in Delphi, you can do it in C# :)